# Show the number of unread items just like in the Mail app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am making an iPhone Application which has a list of RSS Feeds, and I want to show a blue bubble on the left with the number of unread articles (one bubble per feed), just like in Mail app, as shown here:
[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible with Cocoa Touch, or must I add a UILabel?

---

If I must use a UILabel, then how do I make it round, and make it's background color invisible when the row is selected?

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have at look at [TDBadgedCell](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/01/09/source-tdbadgedcell/)

Comment: That looks pretty awesome! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Nice custom solution. I wonder if Apple uses something built in for their Mail app or simply created something app specific that is similar?

Comment: The correct URL is http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/01/09/source-tdbadgedcell/.  I tried to edit, but SO won't let me make a one-letter correction...

Comment: @chrish Thanks for the update. It must have changed recently. I have updated the link.